# How can I go level by level to verify the parent starting from a given bottom leaf until reaching the root?

Tags: sql, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, h2

How can I verify the parents up to the parent_id that is NULL(root). How can I go level by level to verify the parent starting from a given bottom leaf until reaching the root?

Pseudo code:

```
Select * 
from parameter_node 
Where name = 'test1111' 
  AND parent.id = 3 
  AND parent.parent.id= 2 
  AND parent.parent.parent.id=1 
  AND parent.parent.parent.parent.id IS NULL
```

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "verify"? What is the output you want? And are you using Postgres or H2? Do you need a SQL solution or a Hibernate solution?

Answer (score 0):

If with "verify" you mean, to simply get all parent nodes, you can do this with a recursive common table expression:

```
with recursive tree as (
  select * 
  from parameter_node 
  where name = 'test1111' 
  union all 
  select p.*
  from parameter_node p 
    join tree t on t.parent_id = p.id
)
select *
from tree;
```

The above is standard ANSI SQL

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=d5ff623a6528023f3efe6bd80f458a0e)